# Archivos php incluídos con REQUIRE no se muestran al pasar la web al host remoto

Tags: required

Buenos días compañeros.

Quiero compartir con todo vosotros una duda que me trae de cabeza. Estoy desarrollando una web en php 7.2.

En local todo funciona de manera correcta pero al subir el sitio al host remoto, resulta que algunos de los archivos php que están embebidos mediante require, require_once no se visualizan en pantalla a pesar de no detectar error alguno.

Para comprobar que los archivos estaban siendo detectados, he probado a establecer una ruta errónea a dicho archivos y en ese caso lanza error de que no puede encontrar el archivo.

Os muestro un ejemplo:

```
<div class="layout_central_usuarios">
    <div class="texto_seccion_logeado">
        <?php 
            require ("acceso_usuarios.inc.php");
        ?>
    </div>
</div>

<!-- Pie Página -->
    <?php 
        require_once("../inc/footer.inc.php");
    ?>
```

En este caso el require acceso_usuarios.inc.php no se muestra en pantalla pero el footer sí.

¿Alguién me puede ayudar con esto?, ¿Porqué no muestra los archivos en pantalla a pesar de detectarlos correctamente?.

Un saludo.

---

Al parecer el problema esta en que la sesión no se esta guardando en remoto. El host dónde estoy alojando la web es 1and1.

¿Tenéis alguna idea de porque puede pasar?

Un saludo.

Comment: Si dices que las rutas están bien entonces es posible que en esos archivos haya algo que en remoto no funciona, y ese algo pueden ser miles de cosas. Toma un solo archivo de esos y revisa su contenido, verificando todas las cosas posibles que debes configurar / instalar en remoto. O ve por el camino más corto: revisa el log de errores, te dirá exactamente lo que ocurre.

Comment: ¿Qué quieres decir con que *la sesión no se esta guardando en remoto*?